# Non-traceable radio emitters

Tags: propagation, fox-hunt, location

There are various techniques for locating a radio emitter. But what are some methods to make this really difficult? There is usually a patch to every vulnerability, at least from the world where I come from.

Comment: [Burst transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_transmission)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that makes no sense. I proposed an edit to Wikipedia for the paragraph - it claims things that aren't true in the causality stated, and also, doesn't back it up with any sources.

Comment: the claim that burst transmission reduce the possibility of localization. The probability of cross-detection hinges on energy, not duration.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If the "hunter" is using a rotating non-omnidirectional antenna, then duration does matter, does it not? But that might be decades-old technology. In other words, the claim may have been correct once (before phased arrays and the like).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo but that would be a badly equipped hunter. If I'm attempting to localize a transmission, and my wavelengths are short enough that I can build an antenna that is mechanically rotatable, then I can also build multiple of the same and combine their reception in a computer to get instant cross-correlation results.

Comment: This is tagged [**fox-hunt**](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/fox-hunt/info). Can we assume that the transmitter and detector are not very far away from each other?

Comment: What's the frequency or band that you have in mind?

Comment: @MikeWaters Is a general question to give a general overview of the field. This way anyone looking for something like this has some sort of guideline to use for research.Also because I found very little information about it.

Comment: @ChinonsaltaPavarottiè well, it's a bit of a question nobody from the field would ask like this: You'd always know way more about what you're trying to transmit, in what kind of scenario (inter-satellite communication is different than indoor communication), and how fast you want it to work.

Comment: I heard that during WWII, a radio station was being broadcast using the tram lines in some city, making detection of the source difficult.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Badly equipped indeed. I was thinking of the Yagi antenna I carried the one and only time I went fox-hunting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMO, your question is too general to give a good, specific answer.  Also, it would help if you elucidated the motivation for the question.

I am a semi-retired electrical engineer, not a security or RF expert but I'll give it a go anyway.

The first assumption is that the transmitting equipment is hidden from plain sight and other non radio-related detection.

To locate a hidden radio station your adversary must be able to receive the emissions.  It follows that you could use a highly directional (beam) antenna which only illuminates the intended receiver.  There would be no countermeasure.

The next possibility is that the signal can be received by your adversary but they do not have direction finding equipment within the footprint of your beam.  This is potentially the case with (older) satellite transponders which simply re-transmit everything they receive in the transponder's pass band.  So, you could beam a signal to such a satellite and as long as the intended receiver is somewhere in the satellite's footprint you can effectively hijack the satellite service (has happened).

Now to the cases where your signal can be directly received by your adversary.  AFAIK, there are two basic methods for locating the source of radio signal.

1. Two or more receivers with steerable, directional antennas (including
   beam-forming phased arrays).
2. Three or more time synchronized receivers (spectrum analyzers) which
   compare the arrival time of a specific signal at their accurately
   known locations.  At one nano-second time resolution, such a system
   can potentially pinpoint an emission with an accuracy of better
   than 1 meter, even if the signal is only a very short burst.  I know
   that such systems exist and are deployed around sensitive
   infrastructure such as airports.

To locate an emission your adversary must know what to look for.  That opens up additional possibilities but does not directly relate to your question.
Anyway, here are two that I can think of:

1. A radio could potentially masquerade as valid by adopting the
   frequencies and low-level transmission protocols of a legitimate service.
2. Direct sequence spread spectrum can spread a signal over a bandwidth
   of many MHz and make it appear as undetectable, random noise to a
   narrow band receiver.  Such a signal may go unnoticed for a long
   time.

Comment: Hi Manfred, excellent answer! Regarding the signals that simply don't stick out among common / legitimate services or noise: yep! But that's exactly what radio astronomers do all the time, cross-correlate many receive channels to try and find the components in noise / interference that are common. You don't need to know the waveforms beforehand! (But you do need, indeed, a nicely frequency- and time-coordinated multi-receiver setup.)

Comment: "Also, it would help if you elucidated the motivation for the question." - heh, one can easily guess

Comment: @user253751 Why don't you ask the OP, in a comment on his OQ? [A comment on an answer should be discussing how to improve the answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). :-)

Comment: In regards to your "synchronized receivers" option, there are several worldwide networks that use exactly that technique to locate lightning strikes.

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility to look into is meteor burst communication. This is a well-established technology. You beam a VHF signal up into the sky, it bounces off a meteor trail, and your recipient picks up the reflected signal. Since transmission is  upwards, picking up the transmitter's location would require being above the transmitter at the time (making certain assumptions about directionality).

There is a short article in [NSA Cryptologic Quarterly](https://www.nsa.gov/Portals/70/documents/news-features/declassified-documents/cryptologic-quarterly/meteo_burst.pdf) and a [Navy Postgraduate School thesis](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a207831.pdf) from 1989. An article I have been unable to locate online is: Elliott, Ronald D. "Meteor Burst Communications in Tactical Intelligence Support," SIGNAL, November 1986, pp. 80-88.

Amateurs, it seems, tend to experiment with lower frequencies, which may have implications for directionality: see, for example, [this page](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/ham_radio/amateur-propagation/meteor-scatter-burst-communications.php). The RSGB [also has a page](https://rsgb.org/main/technical/propagation/meteor-scatter/).

It would be interesting to know if anyone on this forum has had any experience with this. It may be well known.

Comment: That's clever! Using reflectors of random and shape and making sure the receiver can not find a direct path!

Comment: Do you have to wait for the meteor shower to use this type of communication scheme?

Comment: @AbdullahBaig no, meteors hit the atmosphere regularly, so meteor scatter communications is possible any time.  The achieved data rate is higher when there are more meteors, of course.

Comment: I joined this community just to upvote this.

Comment: @Renan I joined the cummonity for this question and its answers, too.

Answer (score 5):

> at least in the world where I come from

Assuming this is the world of arrogant computer security experts (sorry I'm a bit allergic to this):

Well, unlike computers, physics wasn't designed by humans.

So, any signal that contains significant information needs to contain significant power (that's a direct result of Shannon capacity), and if it has significant power, it's also localizable.

Of course, localization resolution is proportional to wavelength. But, so are antennas. So, while you can not be very sure from where an extremely low frequency (ELF, typically used for communication to submerged submarines) transmission came from, but once you look at an aerial picture, you will notice the 500 km long antenna in the Russian forest...

Rodrigo recommended "Burst transmission", but that's really no solution. If I can detect it as anything but noise with a high probability with multiple receivers, then I can also localize it. This is done, and has been done, since the 1970s for bursty military transmissions in HF bands (because they reach very far on earth). For higher frequency signals, you really don't need state actor equipment: a two- or better four-channel MIMO receiver allows you to put an unambiguous direction on where a signal came from. Use two of these, and you know where a transmission came from. In fact, a transmission being a very short burst implies a high bandwidth, and that is *good* for location accuracy. (You need good SNR for low estimator variance, on the other hand, so there *are* limits. It's just not as easy as "use a bursty transmission scheme".)

So, your only choice is to make a signal that someone can't detect as being anything but noise, not even if he correlates multiple observations. Sadly, such signals have practically no information content.

The only thing you can do is hope that you find a part of the spectrum where the propagation properties are so random, and so different in different directions, that the probability of simultaneous detection at multiple points approaches zero. Good luck with that; in essence, that channel would have what is called a "secrecy rate" in physical layer security research (i.e. an observation of one channel doesn't give you all the bits of information in the entropy of a different channel), and we're talking about secrecy rates of < 100 bits per minute for indoor channels. That is an upper bound for how much information you could send there, without giving away information about the channel, and thus your location.

TL;DR: Nope.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109936/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-non-traceable-radio-emitters).

Comment: Blockers would be shortwave broadcast stations: hide just a few hundred cycles off of them - a crystal filter can do it, most SDR's cannot.  Especially if you are near their actual transmitters.  That readily defeats the kind of wideband receivers that would feed compute-based surveillance.  Of course perhaps "they" have hardware notch filters for the convenient broadcasters.  And the game of cat and mouse goes on...

Comment: @MikeWaters removing legitimate technical criticism of a flawed answer to chat is extremely unproductive.

Comment: @ChrisStratton not a fan of the chat myself, but I think that's kind of OK: your criticism stays valid, and I don't think there's many readers who'd rather read >20 comments than open the chat :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton in case you're wondering what I'm referring to about SDR, the cold war etc.: http://www.cel.kit.edu/english/publications.php, scroll down to the 1980s. In the 1984/85 Jondral paper you'll find [this](https://i.imgur.com/MrgyJrg.png) figure. That's 1984 technology, doing SDR, with an adjustable selective bandpass. That was state of the art as publishable during the cold war in 1984. I'm sorry if I don't agree to the "comprehensive HF surveillance is a relatively new development" point of view.

Comment: @ChrisStratton same author, sadly in German, but maybe this [chapter on "reception and localization"](https://books.google.de/books?id=mh6fBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=empfang+und+peilung+%22jondral%22&source=bl&ots=qte-Y4x4He&sig=ACfU3U0tmjX3AB8uNHZcRSbTanLuQM4MwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRy7bulqPqAhUHqaQKHcG2CqIQ6AEwAXoECB4QAQ) (Empfang und Peilung) kind of helps convince you that digital localization systems aren't very new. The [patent](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search?q=pn%3DDE3423569A1) might help, too (use the translation tool!). It stresses the lack of human operator.

Answer (score 2):

I remember an episode of the live action TMNT series in which Mike had a pirate radio station. To make detection harder, the transmitter was in his truck.

I believe everyone here has been thinking about stationary radio sources so far. By keeping your transmitter moving, and going dark as needed, you may avoid detection for a while longer. They will only be able to track you while you are transmitting, and by the time they arrive where they thought you were, you may be long gone.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques.

first physically hide the transmitter and antenna. While this is hard for large antennas, it becomes more feasible at higher frequencies. I read a story about a HAM radio fox hunt where the fox (transmitter / antenna) was hidden in a coed's swim suit as she was sunbathing in a park. The hunters knew the transmitter was in the park, but no one dared to ask the young lady if they could inspect her suit.

Use low power. Low power signals are hard to detect. This does limit how far the signal can reach and to an extend how much information it can carry.

Spread spectrum / frequency hopping. To partially overcome the information issue, broadcast using several frequencies at the same time. You can lower the signal strength down to the noise level or even a bit below. This works best with digital data and error correction.

Directional antennas. By putting the majority of the RF in a narrow lobe, you will make it harder for others who are not in lobe to detect the signal.

Scattering, sometimes you can effectively "bounce" a signal of off another object like a bridge or building. doing this does require higher power as the reflected signal loses much of its energy.

Final hijacking. This would be illegal, but inject your signal into another broadcast system so it is coming from their equipment. it is easier to hide your tap on their hardware than it is to hide your broadcast.